# Shrinking and Moving a Windows 7 Partition

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I have Windows 7 installed on a 1 TB drive and want to move the installation to a 256 GB SSD. I have tried to shrink the Windows partition down to 200 GB using the Windows built in partition manager, but could not due to unmovable system files being scattered all over the drive.

What is a software (preferably a free one) that can:
1. Shrink a Windows partition including relocating system files?
2. Move an OS install from one drive to another including the boot sector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it using [Partition Wizard](http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html)